# OSPF port number

Tags: networking, routing

What does that mean "OSPF runs over IP as protocol number 89"  as it bypassing transport layer using some socket?

Answer (score 5):

IP packets have a header field indicating the protocol that is being sent over IP. If OSPF is sent inside of an IP packet the value of this header field must be set to 89 so that the receiving party knows it's an OSPF packet in the IP packet. OSPF does not use any transport layer protocols and does not know or care about ports.

Answer (score 4):

OSPF does not use a transport protocol (ex: TCP/UDP).

It communicates using unicast and multicast IP (multicast addresses 224.0.0.5 and 224.0.0.6).